# LINQ Group by on multiple tables with nested group by with join and aggregate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having following three Models. I want to join and group them with LINQ in my MVC application to achieve required result data.

### TRIED WITH WRONG DATA

```
var query = from i in db.Invoices
                    join id in db.Invoice_Details
                    on i.INVOICENO equals id.INVOICENO
                    join m in db.Mixings
                    on id.INVOICEDETAILID equals m.INVOICEDETAILID into ms
                    from m in ms.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    group new { id,m } by new
                    {
                        INVOICENO = id.INVOICENO,
                        DATE = i.DATE


                    }
                    into temp
                    select new Invoice_List
                    {
                        ID = temp.Key.INVOICENO,
                        INVOICENO = temp.Key.INVOICENO,
                        CARET = temp.Sum(g => g.id.CARET),
                        DATE = temp.Key.DATE,
                        ISSUECARET = (decimal?)temp.Select(c => c.m.CARETUSED).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum() ?? 0,
                        AVAILABLECARET = ((decimal?)temp.Select(c => c.id.CARET).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum() ?? 0) - ((decimal?)temp.Select(c => c.m.CARETUSED).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum() ?? 0)
                    };
```

### Invoice Table

```
INVOICENO        DATE
---------------------
1                2017-01-23 00:00:00
2                2017-01-23 00:00:00
```

### Invoice Detail Table

```
INVOICEDETAILID        INVOICENO        CARET
----------------------------------------------
1                      1                100.00
2                      1                200.00
3                      2                300.00
4                      2                400.00
```

### Mixing Table

```
MIXINGNO        INVOICEDETAILID        CARETUSED
------------------------------------------------
1               1                      50.00
1               2                      100.00                
2               1                      25.00
2               2                      50.00
```

Now I want following result data by joining these three tables with group by.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
INVOICENO        DATE                        TOTALCARET          CARETUSEDCARET        AVAILABLECARET
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                2017-01-23 00:00:00         300.00              225.00                75.00
2                2017-01-23 00:00:00         700.00              0.00                  700.00
```

### WRONG RESULT(IN TOTALCARET FOR 1 INVOICENO)

```
INVOICENO        DATE                        TOTALCARET          CARETUSEDCARET        AVAILABLECARET
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                2017-01-23 00:00:00         600.00              225.00                375.00
2                2017-01-23 00:00:00         700.00              0.00                  700.00
```

Comment: Where is your problem? What does not work?

Comment: Can you show the field `ID` of table Invoice Detail Table

Comment: I am getting wrong aggregate data in result for `TOTALCARET` column

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Its `INVOICEDETAILD` and its `PK` and `AI`

Comment: You're joining the `Mixings` table, This means when it is containing more than one row, some of the `Invoice_Details` will be returned more than ones. You might sum too much.. is your `TOTALCARET` value too high? You might lose the mixing join and join it after grouping

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I have added the wrong result and as you said, I am getting exactly wrong data in `totalcaret` column as you said, how can I get expected result?I mean can you show some code?

Comment: You should join the `db.Mixings` after the grouping. As you can see the Mixing table contains 2 rows, thats why you result is twice as much. You're not using the `m` in the group itself, so you can join it later. Too bad I can't test it myself, because I would need to trail&error it myself. So I can't provide you directly a working example. **You could start with removing the mixing table from the linq query.**

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen You are absolutely correct. As I am new to LINQ, can you show some code or help which shows join after group by?

Comment: @Hemal I've added an example as answer.

Comment: @Hemal Don't; you have some navigation properties in your models? Something like `public ICollection<InvoiceDetail> Details { get; set; }` in `Invoice` class and `public ICollection>Mixing> Mixings { get; set: }` inside `InvoiceDetail`? It will make your queries much easier and "natural" if you do so.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have relations between those tables, can you show me how to get this with code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the greatest features of EF is the so called *navigation properties*. When used inside the LINQ to Entities queries, they provide the necessary metadata to build the necessary joins when translating the query to SQL. And allow you to build the queries like if they are run on objects, which basically eliminates the need to think about joins, but concentrate on your logic.

Let say your model is something like this (showing navigation properties only):

```
public class Invoice
{
    // ...
    public ICollection<InvoiceDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceDetail
{
    // ...
    public ICollection<Mixing> Mixings { get; set; }
}
```

Also looking at the tables, seems like `InvoiceNo` is a PK of the `Invoice`.

In such case, you don't even need `GroupBy`. The first 2 fields come from `Invoice`, the other are retrieved with `Sum` from children:

```
var query =
    from i in db.Invoices
    let TOTALCARET = i.Details.Sum(d => (decimal?)d.CARET) ?? 0
    let USEDCARET = i.Details.SelectMany(d => d.Mixings).Sum(m => (decimal?)m.CARETUSED) ?? 0
    select new
    {
        i.INVOICENO,
        i.DATE,
        TOTALCARET,
        USEDCARET,
        AVAILABLECARET = TOTALCARET - USEDCARET
    };
```

The only trick is to promote the non nullable type to nullable when using `Sum` function to avoid exception when the source sequence is empty. Then the null-coalescing operator is used to turn it back to non nullable when needed.

Comment: Yes, your solution is working fine. Thank you. Can it be done without relations between models?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but why bother if you have an easy way :) But if you are interested, replace `i.Details` with `db.Invoice_Details.Where(d => d.INVOICENO == i.INVOICENO)` and `d.Mixings` with `db.Mixings.Where(m => m.INVOICEDETAILID == d.INVOICEDETAILID)` and there you go.

Comment: Will look in to that

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an example as reply on the comments we had, this might not fix all your issues, but might be a good start. This is my test environment:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}


public class InvoiceDetails
{
    public int InvoiceDetailId { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceNo { get; set; }
    public decimal Caret { get; set; }
}

public class Mixing
{
    public int MixingNo { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceDetailId { get; set; }
    public decimal CaretUsed { get; set; }

}
```

---

```
private static void ExecQuery()
{
    var invoices = new List<Invoice>();
    invoices.Add(new Invoice { InvoiceNo = 1, DateTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 23) });
    invoices.Add(new Invoice { InvoiceNo = 2, DateTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 23) });

    var invoiceDetails = new List<InvoiceDetails>();
    invoiceDetails.Add(new InvoiceDetails { InvoiceDetailId = 1, InvoiceNo = 1, Caret = 100 });
    invoiceDetails.Add(new InvoiceDetails { InvoiceDetailId = 2, InvoiceNo = 1, Caret = 200 });
    invoiceDetails.Add(new InvoiceDetails { InvoiceDetailId = 3, InvoiceNo = 2, Caret = 300 });
    invoiceDetails.Add(new InvoiceDetails { InvoiceDetailId = 4, InvoiceNo = 2, Caret = 400 });

    var mixings = new List<Mixing>();
    mixings.Add(new Mixing { MixingNo = 1, InvoiceDetailId = 1, CaretUsed = 50 });
    mixings.Add(new Mixing { MixingNo = 2, InvoiceDetailId = 2, CaretUsed = 100 });
    mixings.Add(new Mixing { MixingNo = 3, InvoiceDetailId = 1, CaretUsed = 25 });
    mixings.Add(new Mixing { MixingNo = 4, InvoiceDetailId = 2, CaretUsed = 50 });


    // select all from invoices
    var query = from i in invoices
                // join the details
                join id in invoiceDetails on i.InvoiceNo equals id.InvoiceNo
                // group the details on invoice
                group id by new { i.InvoiceNo, i.DateTime } into ig

                // again join the details (from the mixing)
                join id in invoiceDetails on ig.Key.InvoiceNo equals id.InvoiceNo
                // join the mixing
                join mix in mixings on id.InvoiceDetailId equals mix.InvoiceDetailId into mix2 // store in temp for outer join
                from mbox in mix2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                // group mixing (and sum the caret of the previous group
                group mbox by new { ig.Key.InvoiceNo, ig.Key.DateTime, TotalCaret = ig.Sum(item => item.Caret) } into igm
                // calculate the caret used (because it is used twice in the results)
                let caretUsedCaret = igm.Where(item => item != null).Sum(item => item.CaretUsed)
                // select the results.
                select new
                {
                    igm.Key.InvoiceNo,
                    igm.Key.DateTime,
                    igm.Key.TotalCaret,
                    CaretUsedCaret = caretUsedCaret,
                    Available = igm.Key.TotalCaret - caretUsedCaret
                };


    foreach (var row in query)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(row.ToString());
    }

}
```

Which results shows:

```
{ InvoiceNo = 1, DateTime = 23-Jan-17 00:00:00, TotalCaret = 300, CaretUsedCaret = 225, Available = 75 }
{ InvoiceNo = 2, DateTime = 23-Jan-17 00:00:00, TotalCaret = 700, CaretUsedCaret = 0, Available = 700 }
```

Comment: This gives me following error `The nested query is not supported. Operation1='GroupBy' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'`

Comment: This is probably the difference between linq2objects vs linq2sql. I don't have sql here, so I can't verify/solve it. You might create an issue on stackoverflow for this or you should find another way.

Answer (score 2):

Ha Ha :) I wrote the same thing just with method chain...

```
   public class Invoice
    {
        public int INVOICENO { get; set; }
        public DateTime DATE { get; set; }
    }

    public class InvoiceDetail
    {
        public int INVOICEDETAILID { get; set; }
        public int INVOICENO { get; set; }
        public int CARET { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mixing
    {
        public int MIXINGNO { get; set; }
        public int INVOICEDETAILID { get; set; }
        public int CARETUSED { get; set; }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void LinqTest()
    {
        List<int>  ints = new List<int> {1,2,3};

        List<Invoice> invoices = new List<Invoice>
        {
            new Invoice {INVOICENO = 1, DATE = DateTime.Parse("23/01/2017")},
            new Invoice {INVOICENO = 2, DATE = DateTime.Parse("23/01/2017")}
        };

        List<InvoiceDetail> invoiceDetails = new List<InvoiceDetail>
        {
            new InvoiceDetail{ INVOICEDETAILID = 1, INVOICENO = 1, CARET = 100},
            new InvoiceDetail { INVOICEDETAILID = 2, INVOICENO = 1, CARET = 200},
            new InvoiceDetail { INVOICEDETAILID = 3, INVOICENO = 2, CARET = 300},
            new InvoiceDetail {INVOICEDETAILID = 4, INVOICENO = 2, CARET = 400}
        };

        List<Mixing> mixings = new List<Mixing>
        {
            new Mixing {MIXINGNO = 1, INVOICEDETAILID = 1, CARETUSED = 50},
            new Mixing {MIXINGNO = 1, INVOICEDETAILID = 2, CARETUSED = 100},
            new Mixing {MIXINGNO = 2, INVOICEDETAILID = 1, CARETUSED = 25},
            new Mixing {MIXINGNO = 2, INVOICEDETAILID = 2, CARETUSED = 50}
        };

        var q =
            invoices.Join(invoiceDetails, i => i.INVOICENO, id => id.INVOICENO, (invoice, detail) => new {invoice, detail})
                .GroupJoin(mixings, arg => arg.detail.INVOICEDETAILID, m => m.INVOICEDETAILID,
                    (arg, m) => new {arg.invoice, arg.detail, Mixings = m})
                .GroupBy(arg => arg.invoice)
                .Select(
                    g =>
                        new
                        {
                            g.Key.INVOICENO,
                            g.Key.DATE,
                            Tot_Caret = g.Sum(arg => arg.detail.CARET),
                            Tot_Used = g.Sum(arg => arg.Mixings.Sum(mixing => mixing.CARETUSED)),
                            Available = g.Sum(arg => arg.detail.CARET) - g.Sum(arg => arg.Mixings.Sum(mixing => mixing.CARETUSED))
                        });
    }
```

Comment: Yep, took me few iterations though

Answer (score 0):

**IF SOMEONE HAS THE SOLUTION WITH LINQ, PLEASE POST IT HERE. @Jeroen van Langen's answer is very close but giving me error.**

With some modification and try, I solved at least the problem with Raw SQLQuery.
LINQ is not helping me with complex and nested query.
Following is my Raw SQL code that I am pretty familiar with and its working as a temporary solution. I have added few other tables also as per my final requirement.

**TEMP WORKING SOLUTION WITH RAW SQL QUERY**

```
var str = "select";
        str += " a.ID,a.INVOICENO,a.TOTAL,a.CARET,a.DATE,a.PARTY,a.BROKER,";
        str += " ISNULL(b.CARET,0) as ISSUECARET,";
        str += " ISNULL(a.CARET,0) - ISNULL(b.CARET,0) as AVAILABLECARET";
        str += " from";
        str += " (";
        str += " select";
        str += "     i.INVOICENO as ID,";
        str += " i.INVOICENO,";
        str += " i.DATE,";
        str += " a.accountname as PARTY,";
        str += " b.accountname as BROKER,";
        str += " SUM(id.CARET) as CARET,";
        str += " SUM(id.TOTAL) as TOTAL";
        str += "     from invoice i";
        str += "     inner";
        str += " join Invoice_Details id";
        str += "                 on i.INVOICENO = id.INVOICENO";
        str += " inner join account a on a.ID=i.party inner join account b on b.ID=i.broker";
        str += "     group by";
        str += " i.id,";
        str += " i.INVOICENO,";
        str += " i.DATE,";
        str += " a.accountname,";
        str += " b.accountname";
        str += " )";
        str += " as a";
        str += " left join";
        str += " (";
        str += " select";
        str += "     id.INVOICENO,";
        str += " SUM(m.caret) as CARET";
        str += "     from";
        str += " Invoice_Details id";
        str += "     left";
        str += " join";
        str += " Mixing m";
        str += " on id.ID = m.INVOICEDETAILID";
        str += "     group by id.invoiceno";
        str += " )";
        str += "    as b";
        str += " on a.INVOICENO = b.INVOICENO";
        var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<Invoice_List>(str);
```

Comment: Did you check my answer? it uses LINQ as well

Comment: Yes but shows `The nested query is not supported. Operation1='GroupBy' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'`